# Negative right margin in css

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

In the chrome dev tools bar I see these details at `responsive.css:1101`
[image]

But when I go to line 1101 of `responsive.css` I don't find margin-right of `-20px`:

[image]

**So what is causing -20px right margin?**

I've searched in whole of responsive.css but I could not find the rule causing -20px right margin.

### Under styles tab

[image]

### Under Computed Tab Same Time

[image]

Comment: Where did you get responsive.css? We can't really help if this is all we see.

Answer (score 0):

The browser is calculating that value automatically. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin):

> `auto` is replaced by some suitable value, e.g. it can be used for centering of blocks.
>
> ```
> div { width:50%;  margin:0 auto; }
> ```
>
> centers the div container horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

The -20px that you are seeing is on the "Computed" tab of the developer's tools. This tab shows the actual amounts that have been calculated based on the all the style rules that apply for a given element.

So, if you have a style rule that says something like `width:50%`, then at some point, the browser needs to figure out exactly how big that is. This is what the "Computed" style tab shows you. You will not necessarily see these values in the source .css files.

Instead, look at the "Styles" tab of the developer tools and locate the item in question. In  that tab, you'll be able to see the style rules that apply to that element and if there is more than one, you'll see them all, but some may have a line running through them, which indicates that they are being overridden by a more specific rule somewhere else.

Now, in your case, you are setting the content to 960px; and the margins to `auto`. The developer's tools is only telling you that the margin is what it is because of the value specified at line 1101. But since you've used `auto` there could be a number of other styles contributing to the final result and the size of the viewport when you test factors in as well.

Comment: I've attached the styles tab snapshot

Comment: Ok, so there is no line through the style instruction, so you can know that the -20px is being calculated because of the `margin: auto auto`. As I stated, this is being calculated based on all the other information. For example, if your viewport is less than 960px wide, then there won't be any room left for margins. You may want to use a normalize.css file to rule out any browser implemented styles (https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)